# Error creating OpenCV2 Lambda Layer with AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-lambda-layers

I am running into an error when I am using a Python Lambda Layer containing the OpenCV2 library that was created with AWS CDK. The error I am receiving in my Lambda function is:

`[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'myLambdaFunction': /opt/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/cv2.abi3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

This is how I'm creating the Lambda Layer in CDK (Typescript):

```js
const opencv2Layer = new LayerVersion(this, "OpenCV2Layer", {
  compatibleRuntimes: [Runtime.PYTHON_3_9],
  code: Code.fromAsset("path/to/layer/dir", {
    bundling: {
      image: Runtime.PYTHON_3_9.bundlingImage,
      command: [
        "bash", "-c",
        "pip install -r requirements.txt -t /asset-output/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages",
      ],
    }
  }),
  description: "The Lambda Layer that contains the OpenCV2 library",
});

const myLambdaFunction = new Function(this, "myLambdaFunction", {
  runtime: Runtime.PYTHON_3_9,
  code: Code.fromAsset("path/to/function/dir"),
  handler: "index.handler",
  memorySize: 512,
  timeout: Duration.minutes(2),
  layers: [opencv2Layer]
});
```

And in my layer directory, I have a `requirements.txt` file that has the `opencv-python` dependency listed:

`opencv-python==4.5.5.64`

How do I configure my layer or bundling options to ensure that `cv2.abi3.so` is created?

Comment: Can you try using `opencv-contrib-python-headless` instead of `opencv-python`?

Comment: @maafk Sorry for the late response. I tried using `opencv-contrib-python-headless` but still encountered the same error.